# How to fix spacing with a California corner

Tags: drywall, framing

Ugh.  So I just framed two walls that form an interior corner.  When I layed out the walls, I did the typical mark the centers on the 16's.  What I did not account for, however, was the corner. I did a California corner, which means that the drywall is not actually starting from the end of the baseplate (for one of the walls), but rather 3.5" from the end.  So how do I fix this?  It's a ~15' wall, so can I just add a stud 3.5" past the 8' mark and then have the drywallers cuss at me for having to do the adjustment to the normal spacing?

Comment: The drywaller won't care - most charge by the foot, not how long it takes, which in this case, a 'skab in', par for the course.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you know the answer, and I'm sure the drywallers have seen way worse than that.

Answer (score 1):

What is best done is to layout the last stud spacing so that it is less than 16" or less from the last stud to the place where the end of the drywall is located. The idea being that you can get almost a full sheet width from the corner to the center of the 2nd of 3rd stud. What you do not want to do is have a small narrow strip of drywall with a seam 3 or 4 inches from the corner if that can be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry about it, as long as you're 16"oc or less **you're perfect**. Most Corners, Doors & Windows are where spacing shrinks. I've got 2" spacing at the corners in my place & 4" by windows & doors. However, do worry about how you're drywall's going up. **Do not accept a Horizontal install on the walls.** Get Vertical in writing & on the Contract.

Do you really want some monkey-see-monkey-do idiot "pros" **literally ruining** your awesome new work with their **absurd** Horizontal butt humps, **laughable** floating butt "fixers" & **fire code violating** flexible seams & **imbecilic** baseboard twisting bottoms? Of course not. **Again**, get it in writing that the drywall will be installed **Vertically** & therefore **right**. And, Fire Them on the spot if they violate it & won't do it right...there's plenty of installers out there.